# How to create equal spacing between multiple label in ios xcode 6.3 using AutoLayout Constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

How can I implement auto layout for multiple label as shown in image

[image]

I need to maintain relative equal spacing between all label and side space too. I want to maintain equal spacing between label 1,2,3,4. I am unable to maintain relative equal spacing between the labels for multiple iPhone versions using AutoLayout.

I was able to solve using following steps:

> Step1: Place the label or button you want to create inside a view and
>   give that view constraint as below:

[image]

> Step2: Select all the label or button you want to create and set
>   constraint as below:
>
> At First

[image]

> At Second

[image]

> At third

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get equal spacing between various labels,

```
 label1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
 label2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
 label3.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
 label4.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Comment: I will try to implement it. but i want to implement through nib file in most conditions

Comment: Whats now your exact problem ??

Answer (score 0):

> **Update:**
>
> This is now an outdated answer. Also, the link referred to is no
> longer live. Instead, check Apples [Autolayout guide.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW1)

**Original Answer:**

Apple has an excellent example and explanation of the problem that you are facing. You can find the solution [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH5-SW8).

They use auxiliary views for spacing called spacer views between the visible views.

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out you can find it helpful

http://effortlesscode.com/evenly-spacing-views-auto-layout/