# Xcode auto layout buttons not resizing

Tags: xcode, button, autolayout

I have looked at many tutorials and just can't seem to get Buttons to resize and layout properly using Xcode 6 auto layout.
The tutorials that make the most sense just use Views as examples.
Trying to build a Universal soundboard app with buttons arranged in the attached picture.
I also tried putting all the buttons in one View container but still no luck.
What am i missing?
Thanks so much[image]

Comment: Try Editor > Resolve Auto Layout Issues > Reset to suggested Constraints. See if that works

Comment: Thanks Jessica, What I tried to do was put all the buttons in a view and select equal width and equal height with standard spacing for all. I tried to reset constraints but still no luck. Stuck on this auto layout stuff!

Comment: Also, some buttons look misplaced in the simulator as opposed to the preview in Xcode? appreciate any insights thanks

Comment: Did you solved the problem dude

Comment: Did you fixed your issue dude can you notify me that

Comment: I have up voted urs hope to get it back in my answer too

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the `button` you want the constraint on, and command click it's parent `view`.
2. Next, select add new constraint (at the bottom of xcode), click "Equal Widths", then click add constraint.

[image: Add Constrint]

3. Select the object.
4. Double-click on the constraint rectangle (not obvious! "Edit" takes you somewhere else)

[image]

5. Then at the right hand side of xcode the attribute inspector should
   come up:

[image]

6. At the multiplier property you can make a ratio or a decimal of the percentage value you want. If you want the `button` to be one fourth of it's parent `view`, then set the multiplier to 1:4.

This might not be the most ideal answer, but it's the best I can offer. Hope this helps!! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I'll mess with it and see what i get!

Comment: Can I use an the image view as the superview for the buttons or best to embed the buttons in a separate view?

Comment: You can set it the the imageView.

Comment: I forgot to say, you should also set the height the same way.

Comment: not sure what ⌥ click is? control click? thanks again

Comment: I think I made a mistake, though I'm not sure. I think you have to select it's parent view, not the `imageView`

Comment: How is it so far? Working well?

Comment: Hi! Sorry got sidetracked. Gonna check it out more today. thanks for sticking with me!

Comment: Do you think it's necessary to use size classes for this simple layout like the picture in original post?

Comment: I got it working pretty nicely thanks to the command Click to the super view. When I get it tweaked I may post a tutorial for others. Tricky stuff. thanks!!

Comment: WOW!! Great to hear!! Don't forget to accept the answer ;)

Comment: You probably should use wAny hAny for all everything, unless you want to layout the `views` differently for different iPhone sizes. Take a look at this tutorial for more info on that: http://www.sitepoint.com/building-adaptive-user-interfaces-ios-8/

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this 
[How to create equal spacing between multiple label in ios xcode 6.3 using AutoLayout Constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29789961/how-to-create-equal-spacing-between-multiple-label-in-ios-xcode-6-3-using-autola)

You can also check out [Evenly Spacing Views in Auto Layout](http://effortlesscode.com/evenly-spacing-views-auto-layout/)

If you still have problem then comment me I will try to fix your issue

Comment: Instead of adding links, you should write out the answer, then add links for references. ;)

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll take a look and report back!

Comment: If you still got problem notify me i will help u out